# Is there a way to speed up games with an accelerator?

Tags: applications

Title + what i'm looking for is like the cheat engine "speed hack" equivalent, or for another example, on the iOS jailbroken app, xmodgames there is an accelerator feature. Is there something like this for android?

Note: I am not looking for something to speed up my phone, I just want the game to be sped up so things move faster in-game.

Comment: I don't think it can be done without root.

Comment: I have a rooted android

Answer (score 1):

Try use [GameGuardian](https://gameguardian.net/download). It perfect works on all Android versions include Lollipop and Marshmallow.

It have speedhack worked on arm and x86 devices, include x86 emulators like Bluestacks, Droid4X, Andy and others.

Answer (score 0):

GMD or something speeds up time based games being farming/energy if it is OFFLINE, just google it. If you mean the actual game like in some RTS to skip boring parts some cheat engines have that along with memory editor...